# Unable to install ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16 to work with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems, imagemagick

I've installed the latest version of the Rails Installer (ruby 2.2 and rails 4.2). I'm trying to install paperclip and as part of the process need to install imagemagick. Imagemagick is giving me trouble. I've installed the latest version of imagemagick (7.0.1-Q16). I'm on a 64bit Windows 10 machine. What I have tried is the following:

- I installed the .dll file and then afterward i installed the static file (note when i did this some of the files in the static installation asked me if i wanted to overwrite some of the .dll files).
- I used the 32 bit version which ends up in Program Files(x86). I named the folder ImageMagick & that didn't work. So I left it as the installed ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16 folder.

The error message I got from trying to use the convert command inside imagemagick folder is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16>convert: unable to open image 'logo.gif': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695.
```

The error message I get with trying to install it in my rails app is:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- '--with-opt-dir="C:Program Files(x86)ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16"'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir="C:Program Files(x86)ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16"'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

 C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160605-8596-1h37a34.rb extconf.rb --with-opt-dir="C:Program Files(x86)ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16"
checking for main() in -lCORE_RL_magick_... no
searching PATH for the ImageMagick library...
Can't install RMagick 2.15.4.
Can't find the ImageMagick library.
Retry with '--with-opt-dir' option.
Usage: gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="[path to ImageMagick]"'
e.g.
  gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="C:Program FilesImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16"'

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I can't check my own installation right now. But I think I only installed Imagemagick as a plain windows app, made sure some environment variable was set in windows 10. And I think it worked just like that. I will check my installation tonight and let you know if someone has not found à solution for you by then. (Not sure what rmagick gem is. I only installed Imagemagick as windows app, together with adding paperclip gem)

Comment: I confirm i don't have the rmagick gem and this works well with paperclip only. Just install imagemagick for Windows as an EXE file and let it install on your PC like every normal software. add environment variable. and it should be ok.

Comment: Hi. Thx for that. Can i confirm that when u say it works well with paperclip are you talking about it working with ruby on rails? Thx.

Comment: Sure. Imagemagick is not a gem by the way. it is a piece of software installed on your computer. When you find a hosting service, this will need to be installed on the server as well. Just install imagemagick properly, make an envireonment variable with path to imagemagick EXE. and add paperclip gem in your rails app. this should work.